# I need to send the result of below js/html code to mail and also print the result in PDF Please suggest

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a survey and get the result by using below code.I also want to send that code to particular mail and also print the result in PDF.below is the code.and also if there any suggestion how to get the result in new page and from where i can have button like send to email/send to pdf.

```
 <p> 
    Select a radio button and click on Submit. 
</p> 
  
question 1: 
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1 
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2 
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3 
  
<br> 
  
question 2: 
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1 
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3
  
<br> 
  
<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()"> 
    Submit 
</button> 
  
<br> 
  
<div id="result"></div> 

function displayRadioValue() { 
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ""; 
        var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
          
        for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) { 
              
            if(ele[i].type="radio") { 
              
                if(ele[i].checked) 
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML 
                            += ele[i].name + " Value: " 
                            + ele[i].value + "<br>"; 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you cant send emails in Javascript, because browsers can't send emails on their own :( however you could use PHP, because web servers can.You might be able to print to PDF, by doing `window.print()` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For print: Use `window.print()` with corresponding `@media print` in css
- For email:

  - If you need the survey results to be emailed from site. you need to send the results from browser to server and make the server send email
  - If you need the survey response to be copied to user email client (say outlook) and you need them to send it to your email id, check below code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #result, #result * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #result {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <p> 
    Select a radio button and click on Submit. 
</p> 
  <div>
question 1: 
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">1 
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="2">2 
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="3">3 
  
<br> 
  
question 2: 
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">1 
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="3">3
  
<br> 
  
<button type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()"> 
    Submit 
</button> 
  
<br> 
  </div>
<div id="result"></div> 
<div id="control" style="display: none"><a id="toemail" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to email</a>&nbsp<button onclick="window.print();">Send to PDF</button></div>
<script>
function displayRadioValue() { 
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ""; 
        var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
          
        for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) { 
              
            if(ele[i].type="radio") { 
              
                if(ele[i].checked) 
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML 
                            += ele[i].name + " Value: " 
                            + ele[i].value + "<br>"; 
            } 
        }
        document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block"; 
        document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.getElementById("result").innerText; 
    }         
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how did you print only the result part ? for me it is printing the whole page

Comment: Under css in `@media print{ }` you have to set `visibility: hidden` for `body *` and make `visibility: visible` for you result part. Please refer my code above.